How to do Multi-level Subcategory Table in Filament?
How can I do the "unlimited" multi-level subcategory on Filament?
This is what I have right now:
Category Table:
        Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->unsignedInteger('parent_id');
            $table->timestamps();
        });

Category Resource:
   public static function form(Form $form): Form
    {
        return $form
            ->schema([
                TextInput::make('name')
                    ->label('Category')
                    ->required()
            ]);
    }

    public static function table(Table $table): Table
    {
        return $table
            ->columns([
                TextColumn::make('name')
                    ->label('Category'),
            ])
            ->actions([
                Tables\Actions\EditAction::make(),
                Tables\Actions\Action::make('subCategory'),
            ]);
    }

How can when user click on the "subCategory" button, the same table will navigate into the subcategory and allow user to add another category to that subcategory?

First you have to define the fields for the form (modal), then set the parent category and save the data.
Something like this:
        ->actions([
            Tables\Actions\EditAction::make(),
            Tables\Actions\Action::make('subcategory')
                ->label('Add subcategory')
                ->form([

                    Forms\Components\TextInput::make('name')
                        ->required()
                        ->label('Category')

                        // ...

                ])->action(function (Category $record, $data) {

                    $data['parent_id'] = $record->id;
                    static::getModel()::create($data);

                }),

Don't forget to add relationships in the category:
Category:
public function parent(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'parent_id');
}

public function subcategories(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'parent_id');
}


Category Resource:
public static function form(Form $form): Form
        {
            return $form
            ->schema([
                Forms\Components\TextInput::make('name')
                    ->label('Category')
                    ->required(),
                Forms\Components\Select::make('parent_id')
                    ->relationship('parent', 'name')
                    ->label('Sub Category')
                    ->required()
                    ->createOptionForm([
                        Forms\Components\TextInput::make('name')
                            ->label('Category')
                            ->required()
                    ])
            ]);
        }

Category Model:
public function parent(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'parent_id');
}

You can attach parent category or add new one
